# Vuejs access / expose object from within ASP.NET Core app

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, vuex

Working on a project in ASP.NET Core MVC with VueJS as my frontend. I am looking for a solution to expose server objects to my Vuejs frontend to store it in my Vuex store so I can access them anywhere in my app.

For example, the build version / app version, appname, company name, ...

Some of these are located in the appsettings.json, others are in the .csproj file which I can read using a service.

I want to expose a json object during startup which contains these properties.

What do I have so far:

I have a root `AppConfig` class which contains all the properties.

**AppConfig.cs**

```
public class AppConfig : IValidatableConfig
{
    public string AppName { get; set; }

    public string ShortName { get; set; }

    public int CurrentYear => DateTime.Now.Year;

    /// Company Section
    public CompanySettings CompanySettings { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validate AppConfig
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool IsValid() => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(AppName) &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ShortName) && CompanySettings != null &&
        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CompanySettings.Name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(CompanySettings.Url);
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
        // Bind IConfiguration AppConfig section to strongly typed object
        services.Configure<AppConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AppConfig"));

        // Explicitly register the AppConfig object by delegating to the IOptions object
        services.AddSingleton(resolver => {
            var config = resolver.GetRequiredService<IOptions<AppConfig>>().Value;
            if (config.IsValid()) return config;

            // We have found issues with the appsettings config, throw exception to notify!
            throw new InvalidConfigurationException(typeof(AppConfig));
        });
```

*Possible solution but don't like it this way:*

Add props to my view root container to expose every property and then store them in my vuex store.

Don't like this because when a new property gets added I need to change a lot of files to make it work.

So I would like to have a solution which parse the `AppConfig` during startup to a json object and then get it into my Vuejs container.

*Other solution*

I could use a .env file in my vuejs to store these variables like this:

```
VUE_APP_ROOT_API = https://localhost:44320/api
VUE_APP_NAME_FOOTER = My Custom APP
VUE_APP_NAME_SHORT = My App
VUE_APP_COMPANY_NAME = Company
VUE_APP_COMPANY_URL = https://test.be
VUE_APP_YEAR = 2019
VUE_APP_VERSION = 0.0.1-local
```

But how can I dynamically update my version coming from my .csproj file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by writing an extension on the `HtmlHelper` which renders a script tag holding server variables:

```
    public static IHtmlContent RenderServerVariablesScript(this IHtmlHelper html)
    {
        var str = @"<script type=""text/javascript"">
            var base = {};
            base.sys = {};
            base.sys.serverVariables = {""version"": ""0.0.1-local""};  
        window.base = base;</script>";

        return html.Raw(str);
    }
```

Then in my _layout I use:

```
 @Html.RenderServerVariablesScript()
```

For this to work I needed to import my namespace in the `_ViewImports` file.